# Navigation with Shell don't work well maui c#

Tags: c#, maui

I created a navigation project in Maui, as I don't understand more than one page. I can navigate between the first page and the second one back and forth but when I go from the second page to the third it doesn't go back to the previous page and the back arrow doesn't work. On the next page it even gives me an exception and stops there. I would like to be able to navigate between pages but I don't understand navigation through the shell

```
Main Page.xaml
<Button Text="Go page 1"
                Command="{Binding GoPageACommand}"/>
        <Button Text="Go Page 2"
                Command="{Binding GoPageBCommand}"/>

        <Button Text="Go page 3"
                Command="{Binding GoPageCCommand}"/>
```

```
MainViewModel
[RelayCommand]
 async void GoPageA()
        {
            try
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page1));
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

 [RelayCommand]
 async void GoPageB()
        {
             await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page2));
        }
[RelayCommand]
 async void GoPageC()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page3));
        }
```

```
Page1.xaml
<Button Text="Go page 2"
                Command="{Binding GotoPage2Command}"/>
        <Button Text="Go page 3"
                Command="{Binding GotoPage3Command}"/>
        <Button Text="GoBack"
                Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}"/>
```

```
Page1ViewModel.cs
[RelayCommand]
        async void GotoPage2()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page2));
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async void GotoPage3()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page3));

        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async void GoBack()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");

        }
```

```
Page2.xaml
<Button Text="Go Back"
                Command="{Binding GoBackCommand}"/>
```

```
Page2ViewModel.cs
[RelayCommand]
        async void GoBack()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
```

```
AppShell.xaml
<ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage"/>

AppShell.xaml.cs
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage),typeof(MainPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page1), typeof(Page1));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page2), typeof(Page2));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Page3), typeof(Page3));
```

Arriving at page 2 it doesn't back up and stays put on that page, even if I press the back button it will throw an exception

What I wanted was to go back between the pages but I can't go back.

Comment: You mention "exception" twice without telling us **what the specific exception** is.

Comment: Exception : " Ambiguous routes matched for://IMPL_MainPage/IMPL_MainPage/MainPage/Page1 matches found: //IMPL_MainPage/IMPL_MainPage/MainPage/Page1,//IMPL_MainPage/IMPL_MainPage/MainPage/Page1 (Parameter 'uri')

Comment: How can you post shell navigation related question, without posting your shell xaml and cs? Also the exception looks pretty clear. Post those two files , add the exception to your question, and you will get your answer.

Comment: Please help show the code in `AppShell.xaml` and `AppShell.xaml.cs` which will be helpful to reproduce the issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be replicated here. It's caused by registering your routes in XAML (in the AppShell.xaml) and you also try to register your routes in code behind in C#.

To fix the issue, just delete or comment out the line `Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage),typeof(MainPage));` in **AppShell.xaml.cs**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally my project is working properly.